# Performance: Returning multiple tables from Sql Server. C# .Net

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, sql-server-2008

I have a a form containing 10 drop down lists. These lists we fetch by doing 10 calls to database at the time of form load.

I want to know the performance on application as well as on Sql Server in following 2 cases. Also please suggest best approach.

1. Fetch data for each of these drop down lists doing 10 requests
2. Create stored proc which will fetch 10 tables and return these 10 tables on UI in a data reader to create entities (single hit)

Please suggest your views...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

option 1. It is easy to maintain.

1.10 requests doesn't cost very much 
2.assume some day  you want to query only five of them, you can easily combine the data parts. if you put them into one store procdure,things will be diffcult when business logic is changed.

Answer (score 1):

Its good if you are fetch data in one go i.e by calling proceudre onece and get all ten dropdown data ..but it also depends on the number records you have and time to process each record that you are going to bind with each dropdownbox

Answer (score 0):

You can return multiple tables from sql server stored procedure.
Create a stored procedure with multiple select queries.
for example if your sp has 10 select queries, it will return ten result sets or tables.

Comment: Thanks all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Few months back we had a same situation, and we went for option 2 in a way, that we have 5 data tables being returned from different SPs, so we made one SP, with 5 output parameters.

In those parameters we send as Input that if specific data table is required or not, and later SP returns that at which index the specific data table is returned.

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[MySP]
@pTable1 smallint OUTPUT
@pTable2 smallint OUTPUT
AS
DECLARE iLocation smallint = 0;
BEGIN
IF @pTable1 = 1
     BEGIN
          SELECT * FROM TABLE1;
          SET @pTable1 = iLocation;
          iLocation = iLocation + 1;
     END
END
.....
AND SO ON
```

I hope it will give you a better idea.